# Post запросы не работают на сервере,хотя с get все ок

Tags: node.js, nginx, cors

У меня есть сервер на nodejs,работающий на nginx
Если открыть его локально POST запросы работают нормально,а вот на сервере работают только get

На сервере есть app.use(cors())

```
    server {
 listen 80;
 server_name my-site.com;

location / {
 root /var/www/mySite/client;
 index  index.html index.htm;
 proxy_http_version 1.1;
 proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
 proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-site.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-site.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name api.my-site.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://31.131.xx.xxx:8800;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-site.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-site.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = my-site.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


 listen 80;
 server_name my-site.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = api.my-site.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80;
  server_name api.my-site.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Проверял через POSTMAN и в ответ получил

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>Cannot POST /api/payment/createpaymentfk/</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Буду весьма признателен за помощь)

Comment: Какой http код ошибки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил вопрос добавив на сервер CORS

```
//CORS///
app.use(cors())
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
});
```